# Proving $\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+d}+\frac{d}{d+a}=2$ If $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, contest-math, natural-numbers

> Given pairwise distinct $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $$E=2$$ if $E=\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+d}+\frac{d}{d+a}$ is an integer.

My effort:
We have: $$\begin{aligned}
 & E=\frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+d}+\frac{d}{d+a} \\
 & F=\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{c}{b+c}+\frac{d}{c+d}+\frac{a}{a+d}
\end{aligned}$$

WLOG let $a>b>c>d$, so $$\begin{aligned}
 &  \frac{b}{a}<1 \\
 & \Rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{a}}>\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{a}{a+b}>\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}$$
Like-wise:$$\frac{b}{b+c}>\frac{1}{2},\:\frac{c}{c+d}>\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow E>1.5 \Rightarrow F<2.5 ----(1)$$
Which gives two possibilities $E=F=2$ or $E=3,F=1$.
How to rule out the second possibility?

Comment: Not answering your question, but as a criticism of your argument, your "without loss of generality" loses a fair bit of generality as $E$ is not symmetric with respect to $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Since no two of $a,b,c,d$ are equal, what's wrong in assuming $a>b>c>d$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes i agree

Comment: $a>b>c>d$ and $a>c>b>d$ is a different case.

Comment: Is $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ in this problem?

Comment: @VTand While I can't speak for OP, it doesn't actually matter.  If one of them is zero, then $E$ has the form $1 + x + y$ for $0 < x,y < 1$, which gives an easy proof that $E = 2$ is the only possible integer value for that subcase.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Very true

Comment: Just mentioning that $E=2$ is possible for distinct integers, e.g. for $(a, b, c, d) = (1, 2, 6, 3)$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$E>\frac a{a+b+c+d}+\frac b{a+b+c+d}+\frac c{a+b+c+d}+\frac d{a+b+c+d}=1
$$

Similarly, $F=\frac{b}{a+b}+\frac{c}{b+c}+\frac{d}{c+d}+\frac{a}{d+a}>1$.

Since $E+F=(\frac a{a+b}+\frac b{a+b})+(\frac b{b+c}+\frac c{b+c})+(\frac c{c+d}+\frac d{c+d})+(\frac d{d+a}+\frac a{d+a})=4$, we have $E=4-F<3$.
Since $E$ is an integer and $1<E<3$, we have $E=2$.

---

The proof above does not require any one of $a,b,c,d$ be integer. What is needed is $a,b,c,d>0$.

Comment: Why Martin has deleted the solution?

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla I did not have time to check Martin's solution.  It looked someone complained that his solution might contain mistake.

Comment: $E$ can be as close to $1$ or $3$ as possible. Check $(a,b,c,d)=(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ or $(x^3, x^2, x, 1)$, where $x\to\infty$.

Comment: My “solution” was simply wrong (an estimate in the wrong direction).